# UIWebView - turn scaling off?

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a web page which simply prints the browser width and height.

I have an ios app which has only a UIWebView. The webview is the full width of the screen. On my iphone 4S (retina), the page above reports that the client width is 320 pixels (unexpected).

When I load the same page using mobile safari, the page reports that the browser width is 980 pixels (expected).

Is there some property of UIWebView that's trying to scale things so they appear like the original iphone width dimension (320)? I'd like to know if it's possible to stop that from happening. This is a default UIWebView, app created with xcode 4.5,

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What do you have scalePagesToFit set to?  Also, device pixels are not the same as CSS pixels.  This article may help you...

http://blog.iwalt.com/2010/06/targeting-the-iphone-4-retina-display-with-css3-media-queries.html

Comment: Hi, yeah I see what the article says, but I do want to have a surface that has 1 css pixel to 1 screen pixel. This is because I'm using a canvas element. I can't figure out what UIWebView is doing here to force the page to think it's only 320 pixels wide.

Comment: Oh and I don't have scalePagesToFit set to anything - the docs say it defaults to FALSE, which is what I want. I want a 1:1 mapping.